# Synthesis discrete time signal from fourier coefficients

Tags: fourier-series

Following information is given about a signal $x[n]$

1. $x[n]$ is real and even signal
2. $x[n]$ has a period $N=10$ and Fourier coefficients $a_k$
3. $a_{11}=5$
4. $\frac1 {10}\sum_{n=0}^9 |x[n]|^2=50$

**How can we obtain $x[n]$ from these information?**
I know the first info makes the Fourier coefficients real and even, third info makes the Fourier coefficient $a_1=a_{11}=5$(since Fourier coeffs are also periodic with N=10) and fourth info is Parsevals theorem.

Comment: Is it a homework of some kind?

Comment: No, Book exercise, I have the final answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you indicated, Fourier coefficients are even from first point. This tells you that $a_9 = a_1$, so $a_9 = 5$.

Then from Parseval's theorem, you get

$$
   \begin{align}
    \frac{1}{10} \sum_{n=0}^9 \left|x[n]\right|^2 &= \sum_{k=0}^9 \left|a_k\right|^2 \\
     &= 50
   \end{align}
   $$

Since $a_1^2 + a_9^2 = 50$, the other coefficients must be 0.

Then $x[n]$ can be computed as:

$$
   \begin{align}
    x[n] &= \sum_{k=0}^9 a_k \exp(2\pi j n k / 10) \\
         &= a_1 \exp(2\pi j n / 10) + a_9 \exp(2\pi j n \cdot 9 /10) \\
         &= a_1 \exp(2\pi j n / 10) + a_9 \exp(-2\pi j n /10) \\
         &= a_1\left[\exp(2\pi j n / 10) + \exp(-2\pi j n /10)\right] \\
         &= 2 a_1 \cos(2\pi n/10) \\
         &= 10 \cos(2\pi n/10)
   \end{align}
   $$

Comment: The final answer is $x[n]=10\cos(\frac{n\pi}{5})$

Comment: How does $a_9$ become $a_1$. Isn't it $a_1=a_{11}$

Comment: By symmetry (even Fourier coefficients), $a_{10} = a_0$, $a_9 = a_1$, $a_8 = a_2$, ... You _also_ have $a_{11} = a_1$ from periodicity.

Comment: since $a_k$s are even shouldn't $a_0$ be non_zero

Comment: If $a_k$s were odd then $a_0$ would have to be 0. But since $a_k$s are even, $a_0$ can be anything including 0.